# General InkScape, Unity3D (and other free tools) Licencing

Tags: unity-game-engine, inkscape

I know that this is going to be kind of a silly question (I'm sorry; I tried googling, but I'm still a little confused). Here's what I want to know.

Suppose that I create an asset/game with InkScape/Unity3D (or any other freeware/open source tool). Do I need permission from the organization who made the freeware/open source tool to use the created asset for commercial purposes?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What *cjmarsh* says is definitely true about software licensing in general. Although, I would not be that insistent on talking to a lawyer (unless the project generates large amounts of money, that is).

Yet, I'd like to add a brief point about the difference in the tools OP is asking about (`inkscape` and `unity`):

#### inkscape

You are not bound by `inkscape`'s license in distributing drawings produced by it.  The license is about *code distribution*, which means the code of `inkscape` itself.  The resulting drawing of an `inkscape` project is in `SVG` (or some other format depending on preference).

`SVG` is a standard on its own, [published by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/), and does not contain any piece of code from `inkscape`.

#### unity

On the other hand, when developing with `unity` you are using `API` calls that originate from the `unity` libraries themselves (possibly wrapped by extra functions for whichever language you're using).  Moreover, you project needs to link against the `unity` libraries in order to work.

Since your project will use pieces of `unity` code, you're bound by the license obligations from `unity`.

Answer (score 0):

Software licensing is a complicated topic and to get a definitive answer to your question you'll have to speak to a lawyer. In layman's terms: you can use open source software for commercial purposes but there are often caveats depending on the specific license used. I should also note that Unity3D is not open source, however you can use the personal edition if you gross less than $100k annually. For more details check out their [licensing page](https://unity3d.com/legal/eula).

Inkscape on the other hand is free and open source with a good license for content creators: the GNU General Public License so "In short, this means you are free to use and distribute Inkscape for any purpose, commercial or non-commercial, without any restrictions. You are also free to modify the program as you wish, but with the only restriction that if you distribute the modified version, you must provide access to the source code of the distributed version."

There are quite a few different licenses like the most liberal of all CC0 Public Domain, a license that essentially puts your stuff in the public domain, making it completely free for any purpose to everyone, without you needing to be dead for 60 years. Then there are licenses like the LGPL which still lets you use it for commerical purposes but requires you to publicly disclose any changes made to the code that was under the license and if you embed it in your application (statically link it) then you have to release your product under the same license. There's also the kind of license like CC BY 3.0, a Creative Commons license that lets you do whatever you want so long as you give an attribution, include the license, and mention if it was modified. [Here's a list](https://opensource.org/licenses/category) of more open source licenses to give you an idea of how many there are.

Without paying the fees to consult a lawyer like everyone will tell you to do and nobody actually does you can check out summaries of the different licenses at sites like [tldrlegal.com](https://tldrlegal.com/) as well as read through them yourself and check out the licensing page on the individual sites of the software you use. In my opinion the software author's intention for distributing the software is more important to recognize than the legalese. Although you should also recognize the legalese.

Bottom line is you don't need explicit permission from the author because they already give it in the form of an open source license, so long as you satisfy the conditions of the license.